# unable to install Xam.Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome 1.0.10

Tags: installation, xamarin.forms, font-awesome, nuget-package

I am trying to install Xam.Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome 1.0.10 in my xamarin forms project, but I am getting the following error. Anybody had success with this ? I have xamarin forms 2.3.107 installed

> Could not install package 'Xam.Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome 1.0.10'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

if anybody has a working solution please help me

Comment: I had a similar issue installing a nuget package. My workaround was to download the package myself and reference it without using nuget.

Comment: Okay thank you. So we need to reference pcl libraries in PCL Project and platform specific libraries in platform projects right ?

Comment: yes. I had other issues that might be related to this but I had to create a .shproj and only use functions from the package in that project. I had an interface in the droid project and implemented it in the shproj. Not sure if that's relevant to you though

Comment: Mine is PCL, I need to if I can do this. Anyway thank you for the info